# Prolog trying values until they are correct and then return them

Tags: prolog

I am trying to do a `rule` in `Prolog`, where I check if it fits, if it does not, I increase and check again until it fits. But my problem is that when I find out the numbers where it `fits` and try to return them, the original numbers stay the same.

** Please note that this is not the original rule, mine is a lot longer and would be too much to write here, but I tried to make it as simple as possible. 
Also the structure must remain the same.

```
make_it_fit(X,Y):-
    does_it_fit(X, Y),
    write(['Nums ', X,Y]).

%--- Check if fits, if not then increase number and check until fits
does_it_fit(X,Y):-
   (fits(X,Y));
   (find_new(X,Y,X1,Y1),does_it_fit(X1,Y1)).
```

So when I call :

```
?- make_it_fit(5,5).
```

It goes to the `does_it_fit(5,5)`, does the `fits(5,5)`, finds out that it does not fit, increases the numbers to `(6,6)` and calls the `does_it_fit(6,6)`, then it checks the `fits(6,6)`, finds out that it does fit and returns.

Now when I am writing out the results just to see them, It still prints out the `(5,5)`, not `(6,6)`.

What am I doing wrong here?

If I did not explain it clearly enough, then do tell and I will try to explain it further.

Comment: I think you're hoping that somehow `X` and `Y` will be reassigned to new values after `does_it_fit(X,Y)` concludes, but that isn't how Prolog works. You need to "pass back" the new values `X1` and `Y1`. `does_it_fit(X, Y, X, Y) :- fits(X, Y). does_it_fit(X,Y,XN,YN) :- \+ fits(X,Y), find_new(X,Y,X1,Y1), does_it_fit(X1,Y1,XN,YN).`

Comment: @DanielLyons yep, that was what I was trying to do and your answer helped me solve it. If you have the will and time then you can answer the question with that and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is essentially that you are expecting X and Y to be reassigned somehow during the call to `does_it_fit/2` and have obtained new values afterwards. But Prolog variables are not "assignables," they work more like variables in math, so you will need to provide another set of variables for the results to be placed.

```
does_it_fit(X, Y, X , Y ) :- fits(X, Y). 
does_it_fit(X, Y, XN, YN) :- 
    \+ fits(X,Y), 
    find_new(X, Y, X1, Y1), 
    does_it_fit(X1, Y1, XN, YN).
```

Then the call to `make_it_fit/2` will have to change as well:

```
make_it_fit(X,Y):-
    does_it_fit(X, Y, XN, YN),
    write(['Nums ', XN, YN]).
```